# How do I extract all the values of estquant using R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, minimum, distinct-values

I don't know how to extract each value of estquant from this loop. What code should I add at the end that gives me all the values instead of just one!

```
p <- 0.5
m <- 2
d1 <- as.matrix(d);d1
for (i in 1:m){
  Xj <- d1[,i]
  nj <- length(Xj)
  Fj <- pbeta(Fx,i,nj+1-i)
  a <- pbeta(p,i,nj+1-i)
  estFj <- knots(ecdf(Xj))
  estquant <- min(estFj[estFj >= a])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `estquant` to be a vector of length `m`.
So:

```
p <- 0.5
m <- 2
d1 <- as.matrix(d);d1
estquant <- numeric(m)
for (i in 1:m){
  Xj <- d1[,i]
  nj <- length(Xj)
  Fj <- pbeta(Fx,i,nj+1-i)
  a <- pbeta(p,i,nj+1-i)
  estFj <- knots(ecdf(Xj))
  estquant[i] <- min(estFj[estFj >= a])
}
estquant
```

(It's important to predefine an object when assigning values to it 1-by-1 in a loop, otherwise R has to redefine the object for every iteration and that is time-consuming.)